# QGIS installation on a cloud platform

Tags: qgis, cloud-gis

I would like to install QGIS on a cloud platform, like AWS/Amazon cloud for example. Do you think this is a valid solution? For my work I have to upload several satellite images (Sentinel and Landsat) all at a time and perform some processing. I am wondering if I should buy a good PC or if working in the cloud is better.

Comment: Unless you are directly plugged into the server, I'd recommend you work locally and upload the resulting images. Because otherwise you'd have to down- and upload the images for every step along the way, which would be really time consuming.

Comment: im plugged into a server